# Need to add generic <T> in Form

Tags: c#, forms, generics

I need a button to start `GetShortestPath()` function. Unfortunately, the function has a generic `<T>` and needs to have it, when I try to declare the generic in `Forms1`, it gives an error with `InitializeComponent`:

> InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

Is there a workaround to have the function work with `<T>`?

```
public partial class Form1<T>: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ICalculatePath calculatePath = new Model.CalculatePath<T>();
        calculatePath.GetShortestPath();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: "*"InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context"*" basically means that compiler is expecting `InitializeComponent()` but it is not present, you need to add such a method in your `Form1` class, and if this method is defined in another class then reference it appropriately

Comment: InitializeComponent() is already there, once I add the generic to Form1 it is not found anymore. Adding  another one does not solve the problem. I believe the problem is with the use of generic in Form1

Comment: @Doraemon a better design would be passing `ICalculatePath` into your Form class, either in a custom constructor or as a property

Comment: This code makes very little sense to me; why do you feel that it is necessary to make a generic *form*?  That is a *very* strange thing to do.

Comment: It works even if I pass it with <int> but that is more a workaround, the CalculatePath is defined as a generic so I believe there should be a way to pass it as a generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue is happening because you're making this class Generic, but not the auto-generated one that's handled by VS and is generated by system. `InitializeComponent` is defined in the another file.

A better design would be passing `ICalculatePath` into your Form class, either in a custom constructor or as a property. Latter one is better. Even using an event and have the parent handle it might be a better approach. Can't comment more without knowing your system architect and design.